# Need to get data for one specific columns in one array

Tags: php, arrays

I just need to print the data in one array..below is my array

```
Array (
    [sales_data] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [dealer] => DS949
            [value] => 35 
            [mod_id] => s01
            [month] => Oct
            [year] => 16
        ),
        [1] => Array (
            [dealer] => DS950
            [value] => 80 
            [mod_id] => s01
            [month] => Oct
            [year] => 16
        ),
        [2] => Array (
            [dealer] => DS949
            [value] => 25 
            [mod_id] => s01
            [month] => Sep
            [year] => 16
        ),
        [3] => Array (
            [dealer] => DS950
            [value] => 55 
            [mod_id] => s01
            [month] => Sep
            [year] => 16
        )
    )
)
```

See in above array its showing month Oct two times and Sep two times but dealer is different and value is different so, I need Oct data in one array and Sep data in one array for both month.

```
Array (
    [sales_data] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [dealer] => DS949
            [value] => 35 
            [dealer] => DS950
            [value] => 80 
            [mod_id] => s01
            [month] => Oct
            [year] => 16
        ),
        [1] => Array (
            [dealer] => DS949
            [value] => 25
            [dealer] => DS950
            [value] => 55 
            [mod_id] => s01
            [month] => Sep
            [year] => 16
        )
    )
)
```

Here is my code:

```
    $all_custom_data = $this->front_model->get_period_data($mod_id,$month,$year,$manu,$city);
    array_push($all_custom_dataarr, $all_custom_data);
}
$arrFinal=array();
$i=0;
$month=array();
foreach($all_custom_dataarr as $custom_data1){
    foreach($custom_data1 as $custom_data){
        $month[]=$custom_data->month;
        $arrFinal[$i]['dealer']=$custom_data->dealer;
        $arrFinal[$i]['value']=$custom_data->value;
        $arrFinal[$i]['mod_id']=$custom_data->mod_id;
        $arrFinal[$i]['month']=$custom_data->month;
        $arrFinal[$i]['year']=$custom_data->year;
        $i++;
    }
}

$data['sales_data']=array_unique($arrFinal, SORT_REGULAR);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Tidy the code you've posted. Show us what you've tried so far and what you're having a problem with.

Comment: @amrinder this  is not possible because key is same. And overwrite the value

Comment: I have edited my question with code. please look into this as this is very important for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amrinder, I think this is the best way to organize your array so that you can remove duplicates and easily access the array in the future.

```
$all_custom_dataarr=array(
    "sales_data"=>array(
        0=>array(
            "dealer"=>"DS949",
            "value"=>"35",
            "mod_id"=>"s01",
            "month"=>"Oct",
            "year"=>"16"
        ),
        1=>array(
            "dealer"=>"DS950",
            "value"=>"80",
            "mod_id"=>"s01",
            "month"=>"Oct",
            "year"=>"16"
        ),
        2=>array(
            "dealer"=>"DS949",
            "value"=>"25",
            "mod_id"=>"s01",
            "month"=>"Sep",
            "year"=>"16"
        ),
        3=>array(
            "dealer"=>"DS950",
            "value"=>"55",
            "mod_id"=>"s01",
            "month"=>"Sep",
            "year"=>"16"
        )
    )
);

foreach($all_custom_dataarr["sales_data"] as $array){
    $new_array[$array["year"]][$array["month"]][$array["dealer"]]["mod_id"]=$array["mod_id"];   
    $new_array[$array["year"]][$array["month"]][$array["dealer"]]["value"]=$array["value"]; 
}

echo "<pre>";
var_export($new_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

yields...

```
$new_array = array(
                 16 => array(
                    'Oct' => array(
                        'DS949' => array('mod_id'=>'s01','value'=>'35'),
                        'DS950' => array('mod_id'=>'s01','value'=>'80')
                     ),
                    'Sep' => array(
                        'DS949' => array('mod_id'=>'s01','value'=>'25'),
                        'DS950' => array('mod_id'=>'s01','value'=>'55'),
                     ),
                 ),
             );
```

This array structure allows you to logically group values and sub-arrays using unique keys.

If there are any duplicate `year-month-dealer-mod_id` or `year-month-dealer-value` values, they will overwrite the earlier value (as a consequence of building the new array in the foreach loop).

If you have multiple years, or multiple months, or multiple dealers, the data will be separated
        and easily access because of the new associative key names.

For example, if you specifically want to know the `mod_id` and `value` values for `DS950` in `Oct` of `16` you use:

`$new_array["16"]["Oct"]["DS950"]["mod_id"]` and `$new_array["16"]["Oct"]["DS950"]["value"]`

or

```
foreach($new_array["16"]["Oct"]["DS950"] as $key=>$value){
    echo "$key = $value<br>";
}
```